# UserCreationForm extension not making fields in the model

Tags: django

I have extended the Usercreationform as follows:
//forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = EmailField(label=_("Email address"), required=True,
        help_text=_("Required."))
    city= forms.CharField(label= _("City"),max_length=20, required=True)
    state= forms.CharField(label= _("State"),max_length=20, required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email", "password1", "password2","city","state")

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        user.city = self.cleaned_data["city"]
        user.state = self.cleaned_data["state"]

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

This works fine till the form part. the template shows all these fields but there is a problem here. the fields that i added like city,state,etc are showing on the form but when i query like User.city or anything except the inbuilt, it gives me that User has no attribute city...this means that the fields are not being created in the in-built User model...So how do i do it?

Comment: HI can you look at this https://chriskief.com/2012/12/17/subclass-a-django-model-form-and-add-extra-fields/

Comment: but its not using the django in-built contrib-auth?

Comment: But the built-in User class *doesn't* have a city field. Why do you think it should?

Comment: i want city to be a field in my customized user

Answer (score 0):

It's a common problem. Ok do you have a complete form to your user, but your model (user) are complete? So wath you need to implement is an extension of your user model (to add your custom fields). [How to Extend Django User Model](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html) will help you..

Comment: in the last part, EXTENDING USER MODEL USING A CUSTOM MODE EXTENDING ABSTRACTUSER, we don't have to do anything in forms.py right? and how will the form be generated then?

Comment: In reality yes, you need to make your form to "AbstractUser". In this case you can use simple model form...

Comment: can you give a little code to support what you said? i'm a little perplexed here.